# What is the meaning of the character in this picture?

Tags: meaning

I was wondering if someone here could tell me the meaning of this word/
expression in this image. [image]

Thanks so much.

Comment: It might help to rotate the image 180°.

Answer (score 7):

That is an upside-down 「光{ひかり}」("light") in cursive writing.

[image]